# Inflection Point of Time Series and cumulative function?

Tags: time-series, covid-19

I am reading the paper from here: https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.03.25.20043893v1

The problem is to predict the inflection point of daily Covid cases.

The method that is employed is to estimate the cumulative case as function of time $t$ as $I(t) = c t^w e^{-d t}$ (with $c,d,w$ being parameters to be estimated from data) and solving for $\frac{dI}{dt} = 0$, which gives $t = \frac{-w}{d}$.

[image]

[image]

But I do not see why the maximum point of the cumulative function would give me the inflection point.

For the inflection point, I would want $f''(t) = 0$ where $f(t)$ is the function of daily cases with respect to time $t$.

Then the function $I$ is just $I(t) = \int_0^t f(x) dx$, and $I'(t) = f(t)$, which means $I'(t) = 0$ just means $f(t) = 0$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How many derivatives do you want to take?  One or two??

Comment: @whuber What do you mean?

Comment: You state that to find an inflection point, you look at zeros of the *second* derivative (of $I$).  Your question concerns the *first* derivative of $I$ only. The second derivative of $I$ is $f^\prime,$ not $f.$

Comment: @whuber I want to find $f''$, but it seems like the paper is only computing $I' = f$ is what I was confused about.

Comment: I can't tell, because no definition of $f$ appears in your extracts of the paper.

Comment: @whuber I is the function of the cumulative daily cases, so $I(t) = \int_0^t f(x)dx$, where $f$ is the function of daily cases.

Comment: I cannot square that with equation (2), which makes it look like $f$ is a function of $I$ (which it is, implicitly, but just not *that* function).

Comment: @whuber I don't really understand the $f(I)$ notation but isn't equation 2 $\frac{dI}{dt}$ instead of it being in terms of $f$?

Comment: I suspect it's either a typographical error or bad notation and certainly it's bad exposition.  Equation $(2)$ computes the derivative of $I(T)$ w.r.t. $T$--"$f$" plays no role--and uses that to *maximize* $I,$ not to find an inflection point. It is clear that $I(t)$ is *not* the cumulative case count, because asymptotically as $t$ grows $I(t)$ shrinks to $0.$ Probably the cumulative case count will be expressed as $\int_0^T I(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$

Comment: @whuber at least about $I(t)$ shrinking to $0$, they mention that any point after $t_{max}$ is irrelevant for predicting the inflection point(where $t_{max}$ is the point $I(t)$ is maximized)

Comment: That's because each function in this class has a unique global maximum.  Everything in the quoted material points to $I$ being the infection *rate* and not the "number of cumulative infections:" therein lies the error and the ensuing confusion.

Comment: @whuber Ah so I(t) = f'(t) is what you mean, I guess I misread that, thanks.

Comment: I don't think you misread it: the exposition is horrible.